# E-mail do comprador do paypal retorna no formato incorreto

Tags: php, mysql

Olá,

Tenho um ecommerce e estou implementando algumas mudanças incluindo o express checkout do paypal, a api que estou utilizando é a fornecida pelo paypal. O problema é que ao retornar os dados e pegar a variável do e-mail do comprador ele retorna o e-mail neste formato `comprador%40gmail%2com` deste modo inviabilizando o envio de um e-mail ao comprador após a compra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse formato `comprador%40gmail%2com` significa que o retorno foi codificado para ser enviado em uma URL, pode-se voltar ao formato correto usando [urldecode()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.urldecode.php)

Comment: Solucionou o meu problema, obrigado!